# Calculate $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \ln(\frac{x}{(x+1)^{\\\alpha}}) + \beta x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I evaluate the following limit? 
$$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \ln(\frac{x}{(x+1)^{\\\alpha}}) + \beta x,$$
for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I would advise that you to do a case analysis on the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. For $\alpha=0$ the limit is not defined for instance.

Comment: Is there any more information regarding $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Else I would go through each cases where $\alpha < -1$, $-1 < \alpha < 0$, $\alpha = 0$, $0 < \alpha < 1$, $1 < \alpha$, $\beta < 0$, $\beta = 0$, $\beta > 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With equivalents at $+\infty$:
$$ f(x)=\ln\frac{x}{(x+1)^{\\\alpha}} + \beta x=\ln x -\alpha\ln(x+1) +\beta x$$

- If $\beta\neq 0$, it is easy to check that $\ln x -\alpha\ln(x+1)=_{+\infty}o(\beta x)$, hence
  $$f(x)=\ln x -\alpha\ln(x+1) +\beta x \sim_{+\infty} \beta x$$
  and $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\beta x=\begin{cases}+\infty&\text{if}\enspace\beta >0\\-\infty&\text{if}\enspace\beta <0\end{cases}$$
- If  $\beta\neq 0$, $f(x)=\ln x -\alpha\ln(x+1)=(1-\alpha)\ln x-\alpha\ln\Bigl(1+\dfrac1x\Bigr) $. The second term has limit $0$ at $+\infty$, hence
  $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}(1-\alpha)\ln x=\begin{cases}+\infty&\text{if}\enspace\alpha <1\\-\infty&\text{if}\enspace\alpha>1\\0&\text{if}\enspace\alpha=1\end{cases}$$

At $-\infty$, it is more delicate, as $f(x)$ is defined for $x<0$ only if $\alpha$ is an odd integer. In that case, setting $x=-y\enspace(y>0)$ shows we have, *mutatis mutandis*, the same conclusion.

Comment: How do you see that if $\beta\neq 0$, then $\ln x -\alpha\ln(x+1)=_{+\infty}o(x)$?

Comment: It was badly formulated: it is of course independent from the value of $\beta$. I'll change that in a moment.

Comment: Could you specify why is it true that $\ln x -\alpha\ln(x+1)=_{+\infty}o(\beta x)$?

Comment: It is because, iindividually, $\ln x=_{+\infty} o(x)$ and it's the same for $\ln(x+1)$ since $\ln(x+1)\sim_{+\infty}\ln x$. Is that clear now?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the only thing that might help is to notice that $\beta x = \textrm{ln}(e^{\beta x})$, so that you could then combine the limit into a single expression, $$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}\ln(\frac{xe^{\beta x}}{(x+1)^\alpha}),$$ and from there, it's a matter of cases for alpha and beta.